# maven Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

Hi i have just created maven web project using spring mvc and trying to run it but it is showing 404 not found error whether i am using fully java configuration with no xml and also in problems window i am getting following error

`Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1.`

`One or more constraints have not been satisfied.`

Comment: Edit your question to add much more details about your project.

Comment: Have you figured out the solution to this problem?